# How can I do something like gf, but in a new vertical split?

Tags: vim

In vim `gf` opens the file whose name is under the cursor in the current window. `<C-W>f` does the same but opens it in a new window. However this new window is created with an horizontal split.

How can I do the same and get a vertical split?

I tried various alternatives that did work (like `:vsplit +normal\ gf`), but have a slight problem: if the file doesn't exist, a new window is created anyways. This does not happen with `gf` nor `<C-W>f`. I'd like to have this behaviour as well from the "open file under cursor on a vertical split" command. How can I do that?

Comment: @close voter: vim questions off-topic now? Sorry about that. Where can I ask them? Should we migrate the existing 4000+ questions? My question covers "software tools commonly used by programmers", which, according to the FAQ, makes it on-topic.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is possible mapping:

```
:nnoremap <F8> :vertical wincmd f<CR>
```

With a file name under cursor, hit F8 and voila.

Comment: I've added the following mapping to my `.vimrc`. They feel like natural extensions to the default behaviour.

`map gs :above wincmd f<CR>` to open file in new horizontal split window.
`map gv :vertical wincmd f<CR>` to open file in new vertical split window.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a solution involving 5 key strokes:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>
- <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>

That is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> followed by <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> in the normal mode.

Here is an equivalent solution that involves 7 key strokes:

- `:vs`
- <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>

That is `:vs` command in command-line mode followed by <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> in normal mode. Assuming we are in the normal mode with the cursor on the filename already, the complete sequence of keystrokes are: <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>:</kbd><kbd>v</kbd><kbd>s</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>.

When we enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> in normal mode or `:vs` in the command-line mode, the current window is split into two with the same file in both and the cursor remains in the same position (i.e., on the filename of the file that we want to go to in a new vertical split). So if we press <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>f</kbd> now, the current window is now updated with the file we want to go to.

The end result is two vertical split windows: one with the first file and another with the file we wanted to go to.

Comment: or `ctrl w` then `v`, followed by `gf`

Comment: @philipoghenerobobalogun Thank you for the suggestion. I have incorporated your comment into my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If we're playing Vim Golf, I think the winning solution is to do:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> then <kbd>f</kbd>

to open the relevant file in a horizontal split.

Then change it to a vertical split, send then active window to the left or right side of the screen by doing either

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> then <kbd>L</kbd> (active window to the left)

**or**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>w</kbd> then <kbd>R</kbd> (active window to the right)

Note that the final keystroke for left / right must be uppercase. The others should be lowercase